# Re-write arguments between $(-\pi,\pi]$ - why

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a complex number answer with an argument of $4\pi/3$ and the example said to make the argument a number between $(-\pi,\pi]$ however I don't understand what that means or why we do it (the answer is $-2\pi/3$).

On my unit circle graph there is no $-\pi$, so I can't find a number between it and $\pi$. Furthermore I don't understand why we do that step.

Comment: Negative angles are just clockwise.

Answer (score 2):

It is one of the most basic facts of all of mathematics that arguments are only defined "up to an additive multiple of $2\pi\ $". This causes no trouble when the problem at hand is, say, restricted to a half plane. You can then always choose a continuous real-valued representant of the argument which is valid in the whole domain of discourse. This choice is not unique. Sometimes its more convenient to restrict to the interval $\ ]{-\pi},\pi]$, at other times you would prefer $[0,2\pi[\ $. With the first choice the point $(0,-1)$ has argument $-{\pi\over2}$, with the second choice ${3\pi\over2}$.

As soon as your problem encircles the origin in an essential way you have to take care of the multivaluedness of the argument.

Answer (score 1):

It's just convention whether to use $[0,2\pi)$ or $(-\pi,\pi]$.

$z=\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^+$ remains angle $0$, now to change, negative angles go clockwise, so angles between $0$ and $\pi$ are the same, and for the negatives you can just substract $2\pi$ until you are in that interval:

$$\frac{4\pi}{3}-2\pi=\frac{-2\pi}{3}$$

Obviously adding or substracting $2\pi$ (full rounds), doesn't change the angle.

Comment: Okay so I understand they both make the same angle, however why do we need to change it, and wouldn't that also change our answer when we go to calculate it? i.e 4π/3 = 1.88 and −2π/3 = -2.09

Comment: There's is no need to change... It's just convention whether to use one or another. In some fields one is most extended than the other, but they're the same thing. When you go to calculate it, it doesn't change because it's an argument, and it's the sine and cosine of the argument which determine the complex numbers $a+bi=|z|(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi)$, so adding or substracting $2\pi$ doesn't change the result because those functions are $2\pi\text{-periodic}$

Comment: So is that what we call the principle argument when we find the argument between only -pi,pi or 0,2pi? And what's the significance of using the principle argument over the argument when working out? Wouldn't they give the same answer? Sorry for all the questions

Comment: Yes, that's the principal value. It has no particular significance... it's just a convention. I don't know what else to say I'm sorry, but it's that, a convention, we could have chosen, instead of $(-\pi,\pi]$, maybe $(2.83,2.83+2\pi]$, as silly as it could have been.